# Removing all controls from google maps IFRAME

Tags: google-maps

Following is a code of my iframe kindly let me know is it possible to remove all the controls like removing selecting map type, direction control from following:

```
<iframe width="80%" height="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=214928275585170600122.0004d0fda61d060c1d69e&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the map type controls when using the embed (iframe) method.
You could try developing your map using the Maps API javascript API that allows more granular control over the look and feel of your map.